# Developing BigInt class

Tags: c#, stack, bigint

I have started to develop a BigInt class and i'm stuck right now.
The problem is that when I try to add two numbers with different lengths, the result is not correct.
For example, 123 + 1 will return 223.
I know where the problem is, but I need help on fixing it.

```
        public static BigInt operator +(BigInt n1, BigInt n2)
    {
        Stack<char> sNew = new Stack<char>();
        Stack<char> sTemp = new Stack<char>();
        int currentDigit1, currentDigit2, sum;
        int carry = 0;

        //insert the digits, XXXyyy + ZZZ = first insert ___yyy and then calculate XXX+ZZZ
        if (n1.GetLength() > n2.GetLength())
        {
            while (n1.GetLength() > n2.GetLength())
                sNew.Push(n1.sDigits.Pop());
        }
        else if (n2.GetLength() > n1.GetLength())
        {
            while (n2.GetLength() > n1.GetLength())
                sNew.Push(n2.sDigits.Pop());
        }

        while (n1.sDigits.Count > 0)
        {
            currentDigit1 = int.Parse(n1.sDigits.Pop().ToString());
            currentDigit2 = int.Parse(n2.sDigits.Pop().ToString());
            sum = currentDigit1 + currentDigit2 + carry;
            carry = 0;

            if (sum > 10)
            {
                carry = 1;
                sum = sum % 10;
            }

            sNew.Push(char.Parse(sum.ToString()));

        }

        //if there is a carry, for example 95+18
        if (carry > 0)
            sNew.Push(char.Parse(carry.ToString()));

        //flip the stack
        while (sNew.Count > 0)
            sTemp.Push(sNew.Pop());
        while (sTemp.Count > 0)
            sNew.Push(sTemp.Pop());

        return new BigInt(sNew);
    }
```

Regardless of this problem, is this pattern of the class design is effective? Is there better idea for designing this kind of class?

Comment: What made you think you should use stacks? That's your first mistake. And what made you think you can destroy the input arguments? That's your second mistake.

Comment: I wouldn't be storing the decimal digits (0,1,2 etc). Better to bits of the number in an array of unsigned int.   Alternatively, you could use System.Numerics.BigInteger from the System.Numerics assembly in .NET 4.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
I will fix my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather wasteful representation, using full eight bits for a single decimal digit - roughly a 60% waste of space!

Even if you stay with this representation, you should consider switching the internal representation from a `Stack<char>` to a `List<char>`, with the least significant digit stored at position `0`, the digit for the tens stored at position `1`, and so on. This will let you implement addition with a single loop that adds digits at the same position if both digits are available, or adds the carry to the digit of the longer number.

A better representation would be to use a base-256 system, and store individual "digits" as an array of bytes.

Note that the addition is not the trickiest operation to implement: wait till you hit multiplication and division! To take a peek at the complexity that you would need to address, download [Java's implementation of `BigInteger`](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/math/BigInteger-source.html).

I am assuming that you are doing this for fun, not as part of a real project. Otherwise, there is no excuse for not using .NET's built-in representation of `BigInteger`.